# Autofilter and set field using variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a serch criteria to get the number/index location of a column to use in the field section of the autofilter. Getting an error "runtime err 1004: Autofilter method of range class failed" not sure if it's possible. I can see in the degug the variable is holding the correct number

```
Private Sub cmdExtract1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim iColNumber As Integer
    
    
     Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
  
    Set ws = Worksheets("Detail Excel")
    ws.Activate


    'Identify the last row and use that info to set up the Range
    With ws
    ws.Range("1:1").Select
        lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

strSearch = "Deleted App"

    Set aCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
     iColNumber = aCell.Column
         
    End With
    

'Offer Date: include dates, remove blanks
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button
ws.Range("A1" & ":y" & lngLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColNumber, Criteria1:=""
ws.Range("A2" & ":y" & lngLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'switching on the alert button

On Error Resume Next
ws.ShowAllData
```

search variable then set the cell column number to a variable

Comment: In your code you use `ActiveSheet`, `ws` and `Sheet1`  Are they all the same worksheet?  Might be a good idea to just use `ws` if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to delete rows with blanks you could do that without AutoFilter:

```
Private Sub cmdExtract1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, strSearch As String, m As Variant
  
    Set ws = Worksheets("Detail Excel")
    strSearch = "Deleted App"
    
    m = Application.match(strSearch, ws.rows(1), 0)
    
    If IsError(m) Then 'no header match?
        MsgBox "Header '" & strSearch & "' not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, m), ws.Cells(rows.count, m).End(xlUp))
            On Error Resume Next 'ignore error in case no blanks
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: using autofilter

```
Private Sub cmdExtract1_Click()
    FilterAndRemove "Deleted App", ""
    FilterAndRemove "Decline", "D"
    'etc etc

End Sub

'Filter data on the column with header `theHeader` for value `theValue` and
' delete any visible rows
Sub FilterAndRemove(theHeader As String, theValue)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, m As Variant, lr As Long, lc As Long
  
    Set ws = Worksheets("Detail Excel")
    m = Application.match(theHeader, ws.rows(1), 0)
    
    If IsError(m) Then 'no header match?
        MsgBox "Header '" & strSearch & "' not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lr = LastOccupiedRow(ws)
        lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last header
        With ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lr, lc))
            .AutoFilter Field:=m, Criteria1:=theValue
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        ws.ShowAllData
    End If
End Sub


Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.row
End Function
```

Comment: I need more than just the blanks. I have 5 more filterter/deletes I ned to make after this one. I figured out my issue. I had A1 to Y and I needed it to go to Z, that's why it was out of range. Now that I know where my error is I think I should figure out a way to replace Z with a variable. once I changed it from Y to Z in the range it's working ws.Range("A1" & ":Z" & lngLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColNumber, Criteria1:=""

Comment: See edit above for finding the last column header.

Comment: Hi Tim, I like your edit above, that s more structured. How can I tweak it to look 4 times where strSearch and criteria will change within each loop? For example, next loop strSearch = "Decline" and Crteria:= "D"

Comment: See edit above - move the filter/delete code into a separate sub and call it with the header and filter criteria.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you, absolutely beautiful. You rockbrother!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. I had A1 to Y and I needed it to go to Z, that's why it was out of range. I've update it from Z to a variable. I'm sure there's a clearer way to do this but it's been years since I played with VBA

```
Private Sub cmdExtract1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim iColNumber As Integer
    Dim iColLetter As String
    
     Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
  
    Set ws = Worksheets("Detail Excel")
    ws.Activate


    'Identify the last row and use that info to set up the Range
    With ws

    ws.Range("1:1").Select
        lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


    End With
    

'Offer Date: include dates, remove blanks
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button
    
        'search the column to assign variables to number and letter
        strSearch = "Deleted App"
    
        Set aCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
         iColNumber = aCell.Column
         iColLetter = Split(aCell.Address, "$")(1)
         
        ws.Range("A1" & ":" & iColLetter & lngLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColNumber, Criteria1:=""
        ws.Range("A2" & "::" & iColLetter & lngLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'switching on the alert button

    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData


'Not Met: remove 'N', include blanks
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button
    
        
            'search the column to assign variables to number and letter
            strSearch = "Offer Date"
        
            Set aCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            
             iColNumber = aCell.Column
             iColLetter = Split(aCell.Address, "$")(1)
             
        ws.Range("A1" & ":" & iColLetter & lngLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColNumber, Criteria1:="N"
        ws.Range("A2" & "::" & iColLetter & lngLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'switching on the alert button

On Error Resume Next
ws.ShowAllData
```